# How to use Promise with generator?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to figure out how to use Promise with generator. For that I am creating function helper to print `async task` but seems like I am doing it in the wrong way.

```
const asyncTask = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(() => resolve('async task'), 1000))

function helper(func){
   return func().next()
}

helper(function* main() { 
 try { 
   const a = yield asyncTask()
   console.log(a)
 } catch(e) { 
   console.error('error happened', e)
 } 
})
```

Getting no output.

Comment: you can do that but you are confusing between generators and promises. i suggest you to first read tutorial about each of them separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to achieve. However, if you want to see the output of your promise, you have to `await` it and log it to the console. Your generator is producing your promise properly but you aren't doing anything with it. This alternative `helper()` function outputs the result:

```
async function helper(func){
    let p = func().next().value;
    let output = await p;
    console.log(output);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's generally easier to use **asynchronous generators** than to use synchronous generators mixed with other async aparatus.

An asynchronous generator works just like a normal generator except:

- It's prefixed with `async`, like all async functions
- `next()` returns a promise

Here's a simplified example:

```
let asyncGen = async function*() { 
   yield Promise.resolve('foo');
};
let iterator = asyncGen();
iterator.next().then(result => alert(result.value));
```

(Note, there's no difference between my `Promise.resolve('foo')` and your more convoluted promise with a timeout; both are resolved asynchronously - I just kept my example simple.)

You can read more about [asynchronous generators](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-generators-part-3#async-generators) in my three-part [guide to generators](https://mitya.uk/articles/javascript-generators-part-1).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at the [source code](https://github.com/tj/co/blob/249bbdc72da24ae44076afd716349d2089b31c4c/index.js#L43-L106) of the co.js to learn more about resolving generators as promises.

The [c-promise2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c-promise2) package also has support of generators resolving:

```
CPromise.from(function*(){
    const value1= yield CPromise.delay(3000, 3);
    // Run promises in parallel using CPromise.all (shortcut syntax)
    const [value2, value3]= yield [CPromise.delay(3000, 4), CPromise.delay(3000, 5)]
    return value1 + value2 + value3;
}).then(function*(value){
    console.log(`Done: ${value}`); // Done: 12
}, err=>{
    console.log(`Failed: ${err}`);
})
```

Or just use ECMA async generators...